# How to calculate mean value and appending it to a column? #python

Tags: python, append, pandas-groupby, jupyter, mean

I have an example of a dataset (below). Column ['ID'] has values refering to customer codes A, B, C. Each customer-code has been to different locations (referred to as ['LON'] and ['LAT'].

I am trying to group each ID and calculate the mean value of the corresponding LON and LAT values. After the calculation, I try to append the mean value in the same column or a new column but it doesn't seem to work (runs into an error that the column isn't defined).

Could you please shed some light?
Thanks so much!

| ID | LON | LAT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 62.03755 | 16.34481 |
| B | -50.37181 | 54.94410 |
| C | 16.95291 | 50.35189 |
| B | 59.95044 | 173.64574 |
| A | 31.31972 | -128.33218 |
| B | -50.37181 | 54.94410 |
| A | 23.11042 | 157.43303 |
| B | 2.15615 | 97.10632 |

I tried this:
`df.groupby('ID')['LON'].mean().append`
and
`df['MEANLON'] = df.groupby('ID', as_index=False)['LON'].mean()`

Answer (score 0):

Two questions:
1- You're trying to work out the mean of the latitutde and longitude?
2- I'm finding it difficult to follow exactly what you're trying to achieve. Could you draw the table with what you'd like the outcome to look like?

If you do this:

```
df.groupby('ID').mean()
```

This is what you get:

| ID | LON | LAT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Two | 15.148553 |
| B | Two | 95.160065 |
| One | Two | 50.351890 |

```
df.groupby('ID').mean().shape
(3, 2)
```

where are you trying to append this to?

Can you draw the table manually and output what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank you.i explained it better in a follow comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help Ivan!

To answer your Qs.

1. Yes, I'm trying to calculate the mean values of the latitude & the longitude.
2. I'll try to explained it better. The shape of the original df I deal with is (15, 30000).
   It contians electric vehicles charging records in a City.

- Each ID refer to to a contract ID / User.
- some users charge regularly, mostly at the same charging station or other close-by stations.
- I'm trying to Filter the charge records by Each ID ans calculate the mean lon & lat at which charge events happened.
- This mean values of geocoordinates indicates where the User lives (roughly assumptions).

| ID | LON | LAT | Station | STARTTIME | ENDTIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 62.03755 | 16.34481 | stationname | timestamp | timestamp |
| B | -50.37181 | 54.94410 | stationname | timestamp | timestamp |
| C | 16.95291 | 50.35189 | stationname | timestamp | timestamp |
| B | 59.95044 | 173.64574 | stationname | timestamp | timestamp |
| A | 31.31972 | -128.33218 | stationname | timestamp | timestamp |
| B | -50.37181 | 54.94410 | stationname | timestamp | timestamp |
| A | 23.11042 | 157.43303 | stationname | timestamp | timestamp |

What I'm trying to get is like:

| ID | LON | LAT | Station | STARTTIME | ENDTIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Mean of LON values for A | Mean of LAT values for A | stationname | timestamp | timestamp |
| B | Mean of LON values for B | Mean of LAT values for B | stationname | timestamp | timestamp |
| C | Mean of LON vakues for C | Mean of LAT values for C | stationname | timestamp | timestamp |

Or

| ID | LON | LAT | Station | STARTTIME | ENDTIME | LONMEAN | LATMEAN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 62.03755 | 16.34481 | stationname | timestamp | timestamp | Mean of LON values for A | Mean of LAT values for A |
| B | -50.37181 | 54.94410 | stationname | timestamp | timestamp | Mean of LON values for B | Mean of LAT values for B |
| C | 16.95291 | 50.35189 | stationname | timestamp | timestamp | Mean of LON vakues for C | Mean of LAT values for C |
| B | 59.95044 | 173.64574 | stationname | timestamp | timestamp | Mean of LON values for B | Mean of LAT values for B |
| A | 31.31972 | -128.33218 | stationname | timestamp | timestamp | Mean of LON values for A | Mean of LAT values for A |
| B | -50.37181 | 54.94410 | stationname | timestamp | timestamp | Mean of LON values for B | Mean of LAT values for B |
| A | 23.11042 | 157.43303 | stationname | timestamp | timestamp | Mean of LON values for A | Mean of LAT values for A |

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This site's format is that of a Q/A. Answers should strictly attempt to provide solutions to the question. All extended discussion should either be in the comments section or confined to the original post.